# direct share on facebook

Tags: facebook, url, twitter, hyperlink, share

this might seem stupid or irrelevant but problem is:
I want to make aa button, which is going to share the url and title on facebook(and/or twitter) directly. I mean, without visiting the standard share window of facebook.

As another option, I thought about:
when you click on a share button, facebook and/or twitter share windows are opened. I want to include those windows in a single one. however when I use iframes, I face two empty borders. along with those two frames I would like to add a button, when clicked, the url will be shared on both fb and twitter.
are those possible or allowed? if so how may I do this. please help me I'm so stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can't share without the window, unless the user have authorized your site to post to Facebook in his behalf. [Check this post on how to do it](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/)